# How to display time interval in minutes in r studio

Tags: r, dataframe

Please I'm new with R programming language.
The 3 columns are just subsets of the data frame I'm working with, I also have a Date-time stamp column, Now I want to create another column that will show the time interval in minutes between switching from A1 to A2 and vice versa. please let me know if you don't understand my question. Thanks

Here's what the table looks like

| A1 | A2 | ChangInA | Date-Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 20 | 10 | 2022 - 03 - 20 11:00:00 |
| 24 | 30 | 24 | 2022 - 03 - 20 11:10:00 |
| 22 | 35 | 35 | 2022 - 03 - 20 11:20:00 |
| 54 | 65 | 65 | 2022 - 03 - 20 11:30:00 |
| 15 | 29 | 15 | 2022 - 03 - 20 11:40:00 |

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, it's always good to provide your sample data via the `dput()` function in `R` i.e. `dput(your_data_object)`, copy the the output from the console and paste it in your post.

Comment: Unless the rows are dependent it's not clear how to get a difference from one time stamp. Also, what does vice versa mean? Ideally you add an expected output to the question.